# Laravel Fortify SPA POST /logout 419 unknown status

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, fortify, laravel-sanctum

I'm having a hard time dealing with `sanctum` and `fortify`, I'm using `sanctum` with `fortify` for `Vue SPA` authentication, when I login it works fine, When doing `POST /sanctum/csrf-cookie` a cookie is set on the client side, then i grab this cookie and send it with the request headers when doing `POST /login` to authenticate login, but this is the only thing that works so far, when i send request to `POST /logout` it says `419 unknown status csrf-token mismatch`, even when grabbing the cookie and send it with the request headers again, if i send request to `GET api/users/auth`, it says `401 unauthorized` with response `unauthenticated`, i've done all of the configuration for this to work, like configuring `cors.php` and setting `paths`, setting `.env` variables and configuring `fortify.php` and `fortifyServiceProvider.php` for `SPA authentication`.

`Login`

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = document.cookie
  const parts = value.split(name)
  if (parts.length === 2) {
    return parts.pop().split(';').shift()
  }
}

const login = async () => {
  error.value = null
  const payload = {
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value
  }

  axios.get('http://localhost:80/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(() => {
    const csrfToken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN')

    axios
      .post('http://localhost:80/login', payload, {
        headers: {
          'X-XSRF-TOKEN': decodeURIComponent(csrfToken)
        },
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.error) {
          error.value = response.data.error
        } else {
          router.push('/')
        }
      })
  })
}
```

`Logout`

```
const logout = async () => {
  const csrfToken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN')
  axios
    .post('http://localhost:80/logout', {
      headers: {
        'X-XSRF-TOKEN': decodeURIComponent(csrfToken)
      },
      withCredentials: true
    })
    .then(router.push('/login'))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a result of the way you get the XSRF-TOKEN cookie.
in your login get request you get the cookie as such:

```
const csrfToken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN=')
```

However inside the logout function you get the cookie by this line of code:

```
const csrfToken = getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN')
```

I guess you may first need to check your authentication API then look back at your login and logout methods to check for inconsistencies through the authentication process.
Good luck.